# Read a chunk of a file using WINAPI's ReadFile or something similar?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

Well, I'm working on a project, in which I'm handling potentially big files, that I can't load into ram all at once, so I'm going to treat them like a CHS hard drive, and grab the data one 0x800 byte chunk at a time.

My problem is, I cannot find any functions in the WINAPI that allow me to read the data from a file I've opened with CreateFile, starting at an offset.

And yes, it must be a WINAPI function, and no, I do not want to map the whole file into memory.

Thanks much, Bradley.

Comment: A memory mapped file doesn't have to have all of it mapped into memoery. You can just map small views as required.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ReadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [`SetFilePointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: You can also use the OVERLAPPED structure to issue a read against a particular file offset.